# Running Android application inside another app

Tags: android, google-chrome

What I need to know is, Is it even Possible to view an app within another 
app?
I have tried to find out how but I found much topics speaking about launching apps from another only

For example: To have an application that views the file manager, specific music player and google chrome and be able to switch between them with something like tabs?

Comment: You can launch activities of another application from your application, if thats what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do an IPC for what you like to acheive. have a look at this link. Though am not sure if you can run it the way you want.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html